# change max_execution_time with php.ini in FTP

Tags: php, wordpress, ftp

I'm using WP All Import to load in product to my websites, but I keep getting error messages when importing larger files. The biggest one (150,000+ products) causes a 500 internal server error. The smaller ones a few thousand products each just cause errors with the plugin and I need to restart the import process from where it left off. I think my php.ini limits may need increasing. According to WP All Import plugin my current server limits are:

**upload_max_filesize 8M**

**post_max_size 16M**

**max_execution_time -1** (What does -1 mean, I've tried Google without any helpful results. Is it unlimited?)

**max_input_time 60**

I've tried a suggestion from another stackoverflow user that recommended placing the following in my .htaccessfile, but it doesn't seem to have done the job. The plugin still shows the same limits and the errors are still happening. But as it's done from the .htaccess file I am unsure if it will reflect the changes in the plugin, or how to know if it's had any effect at all.

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_value post_max_size 200M
php_value upload_max_filesize 200M
php_value memory_limit 300M
php_value max_execution_time 259200
php_value max_input_time 259200
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1200
</IfModule>
```

The other solution I read about was to insert a php.ini in my websites root folder, I found some resources that said I need to change my .htaccess file and include:

```
<Files php.ini>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
```

and

```
<IfModule mod_suphp.c>
suPHP_ConfigPath /home/username/public_html
</IfModule>
```

but doesn't give very clear instruction on what to put inside the php.ini itself. Can anyone help?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't only change the file via FTP.
You have to restart your server process after updating the PHP.ini.

Depending on your server you should be able to restart the server process using command such as: `sudo service apache2 restart`. (in case you are using Apache and not PHP-FPM/Nginx etc..).

Comment: I read there was a way of creating a new php.ini for each website by placing it in the public html root folder, that would override the main one on the server? Is this not correct?

Comment: I'm not sure that its possible, but it's still not changing the fact that after changing PHP.ini configuration you need to restart your server process.

Comment: Okay, so how do I update php.ini? I have a master WHM account, but I have no idea where to find it. Cheers

Comment: Can you log-in your server using SSH ? or only via FTP? if its only via FTP I'm afraid you can't. and you will need to contact your system administrator.
if you can log with SSH you just need to locate it.
use Unix commands in order to search.
`which apache2`, `which apache`, `locate apache`, etc..